# Use Effect Triggered Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to do a simple setState on a button with a counter and apply different background color depending on its state. It runs perfectly for the first 3 button clicks and on the fourth one and so on it does this: [counter log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovF6K.png)

Here's the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const changePower = () => {
      if (power === 'on') {
        document.getElementById('btn-trigger').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        setPower('off');
      } else if (power==='off') {
        document.getElementById('btn-trigger').style.backgroundColor = "lime";
        setPower('on');
      }
      setCount(count + 1);
    }

    document.getElementById('btn-trigger').addEventListener('click', changePower);
    console.log(count);
  }, [power])
```

Any help would be awesome, Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, output, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a new event listener every time you change `power`, without removing the previous one. So the first click calls one handler, the second calls two, the third calls three, etc.

Using `addEventListener` in a React component is **usually** (though not always) an anti-pattern. Instead, hook up the handler via React props. Similarly, you'd change the background color the same way. That also does away with the need for the `useEffect`:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [power, setPower] = useState("off"); // Note: I'd use a boolean, not strings

    const changePower = () => {
        setPower(p => p === "off" ? "on" : "off");
    };

    return <span className={`power ${power}`} onClick={changePower}>power</span>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.power {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.on {
    background-color: lime;
    color: black;
}
.off {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But if you **really** need to use an external element, return a cleanup callback from `useEffect` to remove the previous event handler. I'd probably also look up the element in one place rather than multiple:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const trigger = document.getElementById('btn-trigger'); // ***
    const changePower = () => {
        if (power === 'on') {
            trigger.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            setPower('off');
        } else if (power==='off') {
            trigger.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
            setPower('on');
        }
        setCount(count + 1);
    }

    trigger.addEventListener('click', changePower);
    console.log(count);
    // ***vvv
    return () => {
        trigger.removeEventListener('click', changePower);
    };
    // ***^^^
}, [power]);
```

Comment: I'm so used to applying styles via DOM manipulation, without realizing it can be done  Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

If you set Power in the useEffect, it will trigger itself.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(count%2)
      document.getElementById('btn-trigger').style.backgroundColor = "red";
   else
      document.getElementById('btn-trigger').style.backgroundColor = "lime";
   }, [count])

const handeClick = () => {
  setCount(count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting "power" value by "setPower" inside a useEffect who is listening to changes on "power".

Comment: setPower is inside a function(changePower) in useEffect so no problem in that

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up the events:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const changePower = () => {
      if (power === 'on') {
        document.getElementById('btn-trigger').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        setPower('off');
      } else if (power==='off') {
        document.getElementById('btn-trigger').style.backgroundColor = "lime";
        setPower('on');
      }
      setCount(count + 1);
    }

    document.getElementById('btn-trigger').addEventListener('click', changePower);
    console.log(count);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", changePower) <-----
  }, [power])
```

In addition: the `changePower` function should be declared outside of the `useEffect` hook. You use the [useCallback](https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) hook here.